# Android App using Microsoft Band: Java or C#?

Tags: java, c#, android, microsoft-band

I'm planning on writing an app for an Android phone using the Microsoft Band. Android prefers using Java whereas Microsoft prefers using C#. Which would be easier program in?

I have little experience in C# but am currently learning Java in school.

Comment: That' for you to decide. There are camps for Java and for c#. As an Android developer myself, I vote Java. It really does come down to preference, and you will find more resources and support developing in java

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any resources or classes to share?

Comment: Use, again being biased you are going to get a Java related course recommendation from me (and a course built by Google!) https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853

Answer (score 1):

Some prefer to use the Mono-Project by Xamarin.

This one allows to create applications crossplattform. The big advantage is that you can use the classes that offers the .net Framework.

Link:
http://www.mono-project.com/